# How to update set of hash values until final hash value is found using the "5 given hash values"?

Tags: python-3.x, hash, hashcode

I am trying to create a python program that will give me a final hash that has been provided for me.

Final Hash: 
42EE53E049F4E104BF81A517C5ED52BE2D94487A253FCF978CE783A3529794BC using the following 5 hash values:

- hash1: F7002A5259567B1F993E743D3128B6A97B153EACFC7BB914802DCFB43D23FA2E
- hash2: 6E2B86DC5982F533C3A896E66B97D377D09E7988B7E27E9BE5DDBA9F34C325FC
- hash3: 83AAB3327FFF40207AEB5919BD7FB06BAE953324FC71EE35816076CD6480334A
- hash4: 0B794C734A46D75BE2EEE543F714E8D7E2D41D0549D4D8E1167B77B63080DE83
- hash5: EC40BD8242061EF401305485800CA5D63A9AB6DA659221A27C7BFAD3A9694E6C

as well as an initial hash of:
E3B0C44298FC1C149AFBF4C8996FB92427AE41E4649B934CA495991B7852B855

Those 5 hashes and the initial value need to match up to the final hash.

I have tried to create a `while` loop, and I have tried to reorder the hash values for example instead of "1,2,3,4,5" I have tried "3,5,4,1,2" to see if I get the final value.

```py
import hashlib

chain = hashlib.sha256()

#Hash 1
hash_1 = hashlib.sha256(b"This is my first hash")
hex_dig = hash_1.hexdigest().upper()
print("\nOld:",hex_dig)

#Hash 2
hash_2 = hashlib.sha256(b"This is my second hash")
hex_dig2 = hash_2.hexdigest().upper()
print("\nOld:",hex_dig2)

#Hash 3
hash_3 = hashlib.sha256(b"This is my third hash")
hex_dig3 = hash_3.hexdigest().upper()
print("\nOld:", chain.hexdigest().upper())

#Hash 4
hash_4 = hashlib.sha256(b"This is my forth hash")
hex_dig4 = hash_4.hexdigest().upper()
print("\nold:", chain.hexdigest().upper())

#Hash 5
hash_5 = hashlib.sha256(b"This is my fifth hash")
hex_dig5 = hash_5.hexdigest().upper()
print("\nOld:", chain.hexdigest().upper())

print("\nUpdated Chain\nAdding:\t",hash_3.hexdigest().upper())
chain.update(hash_3.digest())
print("New:\t",chain.hexdigest().upper())

print("\nUpdated Chain\nAdding:\t",hash_1.hexdigest().upper())
chain.update(hash_1.digest())
print("New:\t",chain.hexdigest().upper())

print("\nUpdated Chain\nAdding:\t",hash_2.hexdigest().upper())
chain.update(hash_2.digest())
print("New:\t",chain.hexdigest().upper())

print("\nUpdated Chain\nAdding:\t",hash_5.hexdigest().upper())
chain.update(hash_5.digest())
print("New:\t",chain.hexdigest().upper())

print("\nUpdated Chain\nAdding:\t",hash_4.hexdigest().upper())
chain.update(hash_4.digest())
print("New:\t",chain.hexdigest().upper())

print("\nFinal Chain:\n", chain.hexdigest().upper())

chain = hashlib.sha256()
print("\nInitial Chain:\n",chain.hexdigest().upper())
```

I expect the output to be
Final Chain: 42EE53E049F4E104BF81A517C5ED52BE2D94487A253FCF978CE783A3529794BC

Comment: just user `itertools.permutations(existing_hashes)` to try all possible permutations.

Answer (score 0):

You should add *actual data* with `update()` rather than the SHA256 digest of that data.

Instead of

```
hash_1 = hashlib.sha256(b"This is my first hash")
#...
chain.update(hash1.digest())
```

you want something more along the lines of

```
chain.update(b"This is my first hash")
```

If you also want to calculate and display the hash of each item you add with `update`, some easy refactoring should allow you to do that, too; but this is the gist of your problem, I believe.

Here's untested code to replace yours:

```py
import hashlib

chain = hashlib.sha256()
print("Initial Chain: {0}".format(chain.hexdigest().upper()))

for data in (b"This is my first hash", b"This is my second hash",
        b"This is my third hash", b"This is my forth hash", b"This is my fifth hash"):
    hash = hashlib.sha256(data)
    print("Add: {0}".format(hash_1.hexdigest().upper()))
    chain.update(data)
    print("New:\t{0}".format(chain.hexdigest().upper()))
```

Comment: How would I try to find a combination of those hashes to equal the final hash though? That's what I'm trying to figure out.. I feel like I've tried everything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python